# onPreExecute/onPostExecute of my AsyncTask is not called

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my custom `DialogPreference` I override the `onClick` event of the positive button with a custom `View.onClickListener` that executes an `AsyncTask`. My class looks roughly like this:

```
public class LoginDialog extends DialogPreference {
    private Context mContext;

    public LoginDialog(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mContext = context;
        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.login_dialog);
    }

    @Override
    protected void showDialog(Bundle bundle) {
        super.showDialog(bundle);
        Button pos = ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        pos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ...
                new LoginTask(mContext, LoginDialog.this).doInBackground(user_name, user_password);
            }
        });
    }

    public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        private LoginDialog mDialog;
        private Context mContext;

        public LoginTask(Context cx, LoginDialog loginDialog) {
            super();
            mDialog = loginDialog;
            mContext = cx;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // this is not called, at least nothing shows up in the logs
        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            // this is called
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
            // this is not called, at least nothing shows up in the logs
        }
    }
}
```

Why are the `onPre/PostExecute` methods not called? I tried showing toasts, logging stuff, but nothing appears. I verified that the `doInBackground` method is called.

Comment: Because you **run** an `AsyncTask` through a call to `execute()` and not by simply calling the `doInBackground()` method yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
new LoginTask(mContext, LoginDialog.this).doInBackground(user_name, user_password);
```

You should not call doInBackground. Please call execute() instead.

[ASyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) this is in the documents and states clearly under 4th line of **Threading Rules**

Answer (score 3):

```
new LoginTask(mContext, LoginDialog.this).doInBackground(user_name, user_password);
```

Here lies your problem.

`AsyncTask` should be started using the `execute()` method.

You can look up the documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

So in your case the code should look like this:

`new LoginTask(mContext, LoginDialog.this).execute(user_name, user_password);`

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to accept the answer if you liked it. It'll also help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to start `AsyncTask` by calling `execute()` method instead of calling `doInBackground` by creating instance of `LoginTask` class as :

```
new LoginTask(mContext, LoginDialog.this).execute(user_name, user_password);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call the AsyncTask.execute method. Never call doInBackground yourself, it will be called automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are only calling `doInBackground` function of AsyncTask which is wrong

Call Async Task like this

```
new LoginTask(mContext, LoginDialog.this).execute(params);
```

This way, first your onPreExecute() will get called before DIB and when DIB finishes its task `onPostExecute` will get called.